# How to pass data from request body in unit test django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have modified get_queryset() method that looks like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):

        type_of_review = self.request.data['type_of_review']
        queryset = Reviews.objects.filter(type_of_review=type_of_review).order_by('-id')[:3]
        return queryset
```

It sorts my models according to the type_of_review field, orders them and retrieves 3 last.
When I was trying to write a unit test to it, I ran into a problem that I cannot find a reliable or working way to pass filter argument into my get_queryset() method.

I tried doing it like this:

```
def test_list_three_review(self):

        self.data = [ReviewsFactory.create() for i in range(10)]
        response = self.client.get(self.url2, {"type_of_review": "Team"})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

But got an error: **test_list_three_review - KeyError: 'type_of_review'**
Can somebody explain to me what am I doing wrong?
Will gladly provide any additional information.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get you need to pass a dict as data `{"type_of_review": 'Team'}`... if you pass as kwargs instead then it gets sent as a header, which is not what you want

Comment: Makes sense... I tried it, but still got **KeyError** message

Comment: FYI if you are using factory_boy you can `ReviewsFactory.create_batch(10)` instead of using a for loop

Comment: try `self.request.query_params['type_of_review']` instead... `request.data` parses the request _body_, but when you do `self.client.get(url, data)` the data is sent as query string params, because its a GET request

Comment: or alternatively send a POST request from the test case

Answer (score 1):

OK, so self.client.get takes data which should be a dictionary. I think you want to do the following...

```
def test_list_three_review(self):
    [ReviewsFactory.create() for i in range(10)]
    data = {'type_of_review':'Team'}
    response = self.client.get(self.url2, data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Not exactly sure why you want to include a list of objects in the request since your get_queryset method overrides it anyway.

Comment: I was trying to see rather my view works, so I just created some Factory instances. What I am trying to say is that I genuinely don't know how to pass correctly type_of_review in body of a request as I do manually. Linking you an image so you would have a more clear vision: [link](https://postimg.cc/bsrRDncc). How do I do the same via unit tests?

Comment: Gotchya,  I do believe my answer properly passes the type_of_review to your view.  I have added back in the object generation so the DB has objects in it.  It is still not necessary to pass these to the view.

Comment: Well, unfortunately got **KeyError** again after I tried doing what you suggested. It's so weird... I'm thinking about passing queryset filter argument in url. Hopefully this one works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data as query string parameter. In-order to parse it in view you could use `request.GET.get("type_of_review")`

your get_queryset() method will become

```
def get_queryset(self):

        type_of_review = self.request.GET.get('type_of_review')
        queryset = Reviews.objects.filter(type_of_review=type_of_review).order_by('-id')[:3]
        return queryset
```

GET request is not for passing json data, if you need to pass data as json anyway you could use POST method

then you can pass data like

```
def test_list_three_review(self):

    self.data = [ReviewsFactory.create() for i in range(10)]
    data = {"type_of_review": "Team"}
    response = self.client.post(self.url2, data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and your get_queryset method will work as it is.